# openssl and PKCS12

Tags: ssl, openssl, pkcs#12

jww's answer to the question "How do you sign a Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority?" [Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297139/how-do-you-sign-a-certificate-signing-request-with-your-certification-authority/21340898#21340898) was very useful to me and I created my own CA key and cert and used it to sign a server cert.

I have a linux server that I want to reach from an MS Edge browser.  I found that the Microsoft Management Console application would not accept the .pem format certs so I converted them into .p12 (PKCS12) format and combined them in a single file also using material that I found on the stackoverflow site.  (file attached)

My question is does openssl create pkcs12 certs natively or is the conversion stage necessary?

Comment: PKCS12 is used to store or move the certificate or chain PLUS PRIVATEKEY, and a client like a browser SHOULD NEVER have the server privatekey, only the _CA cert_ that anchors the server cert. For MS this should be in TrustedRoots or sometimes IntermediateCAs, and MS cert import accepts either PEM or DER for a CA cert; OpenSSL commandline uses only PEM for lone certs. Yes OpenSSL commandline only creates newly-issued certs in PEM format; since a non-DIY CA should never have the subject's privatekey it can't create a PKCS12.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_85.  Good job my trial CA cert and key had lifetime one day.